My Dell xps 13 with Ubuntu 22.04 frozen ramdomlly
Sometimes, and more frequently lately, the system freezes and I have to restart it. I have noticed that this happens more when I open Thunderbird Mail.

you may find this Super User post of some interest. And also this Joe Tech post too
